# Schengen Visa and International Students

Tags: uk, schengen, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am planning on taking a trip to Europe and require a schengen visa. As an international students, I keep substantial amount of my savings outside of the country, but also have UK bank account. For the Schengen Visa application in London, can I use my non-UK bank account, which is denominated not in Euros,Dollar or Pounds? I believe my UK bank account may not satisfy the visa officer because I deposit money in the account non-constantly and balance is not constant as well.
Thanks

Comment: Assuming the non-UK account is in your name, you can access the funds readily (eg it’s not a fixed deposit) and provide recent statements, why would you not be able to use it as proof of financial means?

Comment: Why would you not use both? You do want to get the visa, right?

Comment: @MichaelHampton that sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [purpose of submitting bank statements](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C0.0000) with your visa application is threefold:

1. Demonstrate that you can support yourself
2. Demonstrate that you have strong ties to your home country - a fixed constant income every months shows you receive a salary of some sort, hence you have a job
3. Demonstrate that you lead a financially healthy lifestyle

With this in mind, you should provide the statements of the accounts which best help you represent your case. Keep in mind that you must be able to explain the provenance of the funds, and the reason behind the transactions.

> can I use my non-UK bank account, which is denominated not in Euros,Dollar or Pounds?

Yes you can. The bank account does not have to be in the currency of the destination country. The important thing is to keep in mind exchange rates and cost of living. There are plenty of examples questions on this site in which applicants get rejected because they do not meet criterion 1: supporting oneself. If the bank account statement shows a monthly income which is too low compared to the average monthly cost of living in the destination country, then it is likely that the application will be rejected.